# How to keep a bathroom door slightly ajar, without adjusting a doorstop

Tags: doors

I have a bathroom door whose frame is not plumb, so if the door is left slightly ajar, it swings fully open by itself. I want to be able to leave the door slightly ajar (about 4 inches / 10 cm) without having to manually adjust a doorstop or other device, just by using the door knob to leave it in the set position. I also want to be able to leave the door fully closed or fully open. It would be similar in concept to how car doors can stop in the half-open position.

Does such a device exist, that can hold a door slightly ajar?

I could kludge something out of a coat hanger wire and a nail between the top of the door and the door frame (see diagram below), but it wouldn't look great. Maybe there is a similar professional-looking product that I can install.

[image: diagram of latch wire and pin to hold door slightly ajar]

Comment: Just want to say I like your idea of a solution.  I'm not sure of a commercial product like this, but there might be one.

Comment: Can you reset the door to be plumb? It is an easy job for somebody experienced and a possibility for somebody who is determined, patient, and has a few hand tools.

Comment: i used to have a decorative pulley and twine with a filled bottle for weight that would keep my home theater door shut. got a lot of comments on it.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard of that in such cases you can pop one of the hinge pins out, wack the hinge pin with a hammer to give it a slight bend and pop it back in. The slight bend will keep the door from going close all the way with being manually shut.

Answer (score 0):

An adjustable spring hinge could get you part of the way there. With the spring wound lightly it could counteract the door's preference for closing so that the door would tend to sit only slightly ajar instead.

This doesn't solve the problem, but it changes the problem from "how do I hold it slightly ajar?" to "how do I hold the door fully open?" The latter problem may be easier to solve: door stops, magnet door holders, etc.